# Python, empty file after csv writer.. again

Tags: python, csv, writer

My python program loops through a bunch of csv-files, read them, and write specific columns in the file to another csv file. While the program runs, i can see the files being written in the correct manner, but once the program is finished, all the files i've just written become empty.

The solution to all the other similar threads seems to be closing the file you write to properly, but i cant seem to figure out what im doing wrong. Anyone?

```
import os
import csv

def ensure_dir(f):
    d = os.path.dirname(f)
    if not os.path.exists(d):
        os.makedirs(d)

readpath = os.path.join("d:\\", "project")
savepath=os.path.join("d:\\", "save")
ensure_dir(savepath)
contents_1=os.listdir(readpath)
for i in contents_1[1:len(contents_1)]:
    readpath_2=os.path.join(readpath, i)
    if os.path.isdir(readpath_2)== True :
        contents_2=os.listdir(readpath_2)
        for i in contents_2:
            readpath_3=os.path.join(readpath_2, i)
            if os.path.isfile(readpath_3)== True :
                savefile=savepath + "\\" + i
                savefile = open(savefile, 'wb')
                writer = csv.writer(savefile, delimiter=';')
                readfile=open(readpath_3, 'rb')
                reader = csv.reader(readfile, delimiter=';')
                try:
                    for row in reader:
                        writer.writerow([row[0], row[3]])
                except:
                    print(i)
                finally:
                    savefile.close()
                    readfile.close()
```

Comment: You should use `try..finally` or the `with`-Statement for a clean file access without these problems.

Comment: Which operating system are you working on?

Comment: Not that either of these is your problem, but adding `== True` to a conditional is redundant (and a bit silly), and using `+ "\\" + i` to build a path instead of using `os.path.join` breaks compatibility with non-Windows OSes.

Comment: @ms4py adding a finally doesnt seem to solve the problem. I was hoping there would be a solution without having to use the with-statement.

Comment: You have an `except: print(i)` in there.  Is it printing anything?  Also, have you made sure that the files you are reading from contain data?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski the print statement only tells me which files that cant be read (files have been scraped from a site, and some of them arent csv). Yes ive checked my input files. Ive also checked the output files, which are correctly written, but become empty once program ends.

Comment: Are by chance your input and output paths the same? If so, you could be overwriting your input file.

Comment: Just to clarify.  The files you write exist *and have data in them* while the program is running, but not afterward?

Comment: You should **always** use `try..finally` or the `with`-Statement if working with files! I'm pretty sure your file closing is not consistent because of your `try..except`. Show your code with `finally`-Statement.

Comment: @NathanErnst no, all the paths are correct. The program executes correctly, the missing content issue occurs when the program ends.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: that is correct, it takes about 20 seconds to run through all the files so i have time to check some of them before program ends.

Comment: @ms4py: i edited my code according to your suggestion. Any mistakes?

Comment: Then your problem is in the part of the code that you are not showing us.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: haha, i would not be surprised. Ill edit and paste the entire code, and hopefully the error will surface.

Comment: What are the contents of `path_contents`, `save_path`, and `path_read`?

Comment: @EthanFurman: the savepath is empty, the readpath contains folders, which contains the files i'm reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`savefile=savepath + "\\" + i` is the error.  If both `"d:\\project\a\x.csv"` and `"d:\\project\b\x.csv"` exist, then you will write to `savepath + "\\" + i` more than once.  If the second path as an empty `"x.csv"`, then it would overwrite the result with an empty file.

Try this instead:

```
import os
import csv

def ensure_dir(f):
    d = os.path.dirname(f)
    if not os.path.exists(d):
        os.makedirs(d)

readpath = os.path.join("d:\\", "project")
savepath = os.path.join("d:\\", "save")

ensure_dir(savepath)

for dname in os.listdir(readpath)[1:]:
    readpath_2 = os.path.join(dname, fname)
    if not os.path.isdir(readpath_2):
        continue
    for fname in os.listdir(readpath_2)
        fullfname = os.path.join(readpath_2, fname)
        if not os.path.isfile(fullfname):
            continue
        savefile = open(savepath + "\\" + dname + "_" + fname, wb)
        writer = csv.writer(savefile, delimiter=';')
        readfile=open(fullfname, 'rb')
        reader = csv.reader(readfile, delimiter=';')
        try:
            for row in reader:
                writer.writerow([row[0], row[3]])
        except:
            print(i)
        finally:
            savefile.close()
            readfile.close()
```

This code could be greatly improved with [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. And thanks for the tip on os.walk.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the python documentation:

> If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.

Change the 'w' and 'r' flags to 'wb' and 'rb'.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Your outer loop AND your inner loop both use `i` as the loop variable. This has no hope of (a) being understood by a human (b) working properly.

(2) `except: print(i)` ... What??? I'd suggest you remove the try/except and fix any bugs that you come across.